# Finding regional maximum elements by iterative method

Tags: c++, algorithm

Assumed that I'd find regional maximum elements in the following matrix. The regional maximum are 8-connected elements with the same value *t*, whose external boundary all have a value less than *t*. In this case, the results expected are one element that equals `8` and five elements that equal `9`.

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1
1 1 2 8 2 2 2 9 1 1
1 1 1 1 2 2 9 9 9 1
1 2 2 2 2 2 2 9 1 1
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

For the first situation, it is very easy to pick `8` from its 8-connected neighbors because `8` is the greatest among them. The pseudo code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        if element(i, j) > AllOfNeighbors(i, j)
            RecordMaxElementIndex(i, j);
    }
}
```

But for the second situation, I get confused. This time `9` is greater than some of its neighbors and equals to the other neighbors.  The pseudo code would be:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        // Start iteration
        if element(i, j) > AllOfNeighbors(i, j)
            RecordMaxElementIndex(i, j);
        else if element(i, j) > SomeOfNeighbors(i, j) && 
                element(i, j) == TheOtherNeighbors(i, j)
            RecordTheOtherNeighborsIndex(i, j);
        // Jump to the start now
    }
}
```

For example, when `(i, j)` is `(7, 2)`, elements at `(6, 3)`, `(7, 3)` and `(8, 3)` will be recorded for the next **iterative** round. I'm not sure whether using iterative method is proper here but I think `TheOtherNeighbors(ii, jj)` could be treated as `element(i, j)` and repeat the same process to find the regional maximum. Moreover, `(6, 3)` cannot be compared to `(7, 2)`, `(7, 3)` and `(8, 3)`again in case endless loop. So how to implement the iterative method? Any guide would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you may create the [connected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_component_(graph_theory)) using [Disjoint-set_data_structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) and mark component that are not maximal...

Pseudo code:

```
DisjointSet disjointSet[10][6]

// Init disjointSet
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
         disjointSet[i][j].MakeSet({i, j});
         disjointSet[i][j].MarkAsMaximal(); // extra flag for your case
    }
}

// Create Connected component and mark as not maximal
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        for (auto neighborDisjointSet : NeighborsWithSameValue(i, j)) {
            Union(disjointSet[i][j], neighborDisjointSet);
        }
        if (element(i, j) < AnyOfNeighbors(i, j)) {
            disjointSet[i][j].MarkAsNotMaximal();
        }
        for (auto neighborDisjointSet : NeighborsWithSmallValue(i, j) {
            neighborDisjointSet.MarkAsNotMaximal();
        }
    }
}

// Collect result.
std::set<DisjointSet> maximumRegions;
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
        if (disjointSet[i][j].IsMarkAsMaximal) {
            maximumRegions.insert(disjointSet[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not clear what does `for (auto neighborDisjointSet : NeighborsWithSameValue(i, j)) {` mean? Could you give more explanation?

Comment: I will try to reformulate: for each neighbor coordinates with the same value, use the *disjointSet* of that coordinate. So for the first case: value of `(0,0)` is `1`, and `(1,0)`, `(0,1)` has also `1` as value, but `(1,1)` as a different value (`2`). so  `neighborDisjointSet` will iterate over `disjointSet[0][1]` and `disjointSet[1][0]`.

Comment: One more thing to ask about `MakeSet()`: `MakeSet()` is to initialize parent nodes, so here I get 60 parent nodes at first. Then merge (`Union()`) them into several partitions which are 8-connected as well as share the same value. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, the connected component are connected and share the same value at the end.